# How to interpret two clauses separated by a semicolon, then followed with a colon

Tags: semicolons, colons

If two clauses separated by a semicolon are then followed with a colon, does the colon apply to only the second clause, after which it appears, or does it apply to both clauses being considered as a single "unit"?

It would look like the following: *clause 1*; *clause 2*: *clause 3*.

So does the colon apply to only *clause 2*, or does it apply to *clause 1* and *clause 2* considered as a single "unit"?

Comment: The semicolon connects two independent clauses that are related to each other in some way; a semicolon is preferred over a period in such sentences because the latter signals an abrupt stop: you could thus use a period when you've got an unrelated statement to make.

Comment: @user405662 But I don't think this addresses how the colon relates to the semicolons.

Comment: The use of colon is this: it introduces a list, a quotation, or an example, among other things.

Comment: @user405662 I understand that, but my question is about how it relates to the two independent clauses preceding it.

Comment: That would depend on the context; it may or may not relate to both the clauses: in **this** particular sentence it doesn't.

Comment: @user405662 Ahh, ok. Well, I guess that answers my question then: it depends on the context.

Comment: You might well get much better response if you fleshed out your example; "sentence 1; sentence 2: sentence 3" doesn't really help. Moreover, "sentences" 1 & 2 represent independent clauses that a writer has chosen *not* to punctuate as separate sentences, while "sentence 3" might well not even be an independent clause.

Comment: @BrianDonovan user405662's comment pretty much answered my question. However, I will edit my post so that it specifies "clause" instead of "sentence", since I think that's actually the correct terminology.

Comment: I don't see how it could apply to both clauses. Example?

Comment: @TinfoilHat I'm not sure what the correct answer is, which is why I asked in the first place. David Bartley's answer seems to agree that it could only apply to *clause 2*.

Comment: I should have tagged @user405662 to provide an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say I know in what sense you mean a colon applies to a preceding clause, so I'm not sure I can entirely answer your question. But I think there are some assumptions and terminological confusion in it that should be addressed. You probably know these things, but just to keep terminology straight:

- **Sentences** are groups of words which work together to complete a thought and can therefore stand and on their own; sentences begin
  with a capitalized word and end with **terminal punctuation**:
  period, question mark, or exclamation point--not a colon or
  semicolon.

  Groups of words which are grammatical and semantic equivalents of
  sentences but are only part of a sentence are called **independent
  clauses**. They must be punctuated correctly, usually separated from
  each other with a semicolon or a comma and coordinating conjunction.
  The independent clauses in a sentence should work together to
  completely address a single topic. What comes after a colon should be
  even more closely related to the preceding clause; its structure can
  vary.

  Sentences and independent clauses are both **statements**.

Following your schematic example, substituting "statement" for "sentence," statement 1 and statement 2 are independent clauses separated by a semicolon; whatever comes after the colon specifically fulfills, exemplifies, or supplements a thought broached in statement 2 and can have various grammatical forms:  a single word, a phrase, or an independent clause begun with a capitalized word.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So it seems that you disagree with user405662's comment regarding it being dependent on context? You seem to be claiming that the colon applies only to *statement 2*.

Comment: If you have in mind a specific sentence, it would help to see it.

Comment: I don't see a way to answer your question in the abstract.  Yes, there are rules, but in the end it comes down to what is readable and makes sense; the rules are derived from that.