# Period vs. Colon?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, colons

I came across this question while studying for the SAT.

> What the humanities teach are valuable **skills. These** include the ability to think critically; to construct, analyze, and respond to arguments; to see both sides of an issue; and to understand the processes that have brought us to where we are today.
>
> (A) NO CHANGE
>
> (B) skills: these

The answer sheet says that (A) is correct, but it does not specify why. I thought the answer is (B) as what follows correctly elaborates on the previous information.

Comment: Hello, Kyle. Though there's no mortal sin in the use of a colon here (after all, a list of examples is introduced: colon territory), the use of both colon and semicolon in a single sentence is rare and held by some to be poor style. Here, with a comma hierarchy (semicolons as 'supercommas', plus commas), a single sentence would certainly be unwieldy.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I understand your reasons for posting such answers as comments, but nevertheless felt that in this case it would be a good idea to 'upgrade' the comment to a wiki-answer, to ensure that those who come to the page consider it on a par with the other answer (and any further answers that may be posted).

Comment: @jsw No problem, it gives me a chance to explain why I didn't answer in an 'answer'. (1) I'd find it hard to find authoritative support for the 'poor style to use both a colon and a semicolon in the same sentence' assertion (though I'm almost certain it's been made before on ELU); (2) there is a gradience of acceptability, and exam questions tacitly require that your beliefs/deferences correspond to those of the specific examiner involved; (3) questions about preferred styles belong on Writers.SE.

Comment: I suspect that the reason why good writers avoid having a colon and a semi-colon in the same sentence is not purely aesthetic, but rather that they think that it may be confusing, as they expect their readers to be unsure about the hierarchical relationship between the two. Related: [How to interpret two clauses separated by a semicolon, then followed with a colon](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/557730).

Comment: If you were going to put a colon after "skills" you would typically not say "these include" as the colon already indicates as much.  *To sew a button on, you need certain things:   needle, thread, button, and last but not least, the item that needs the button.*

Answer (score 1):

I've helped students prepare for the SAT for over two decades and am very familiar with its writing section.

Answer choice B is too "wordy", as "these include" is redundant. A better way to write this sentence with a colon would be:

> What the humanities teach are valuable skills: the ability to think critically; to construct . . .

Answer choice A is therefore better.

Comment: What you offer here as a better wording is **not** the same as (A). This is a multiple-choice test, so the candidates don't have the option of proposing something that is not offered as a possible answer.

Comment: I agree, to make B work, you'd have to remove the fluff of "these include" (= the colon) as you show.

Comment: @jsw29 My suggestion with the colon is not meant to be the same as answer choice A or to be a proposal for the student's use during the test; it is merely meant to demonstrate to OP what a "good" sentence with a colon could look like.

Answer (score 0):

As Mr. [Ashworth](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/21655/edwin-ashworth) answered in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/609069/period-vs-colon#comment1540190_609069),

> though there's no mortal sin in the use of a colon here (after all, a list of examples is introduced: colon territory), the use of both colon and semicolon in a single sentence is rare and held by some to be poor style. Here, with a comma hierarchy (semicolons as 'supercommas', plus commas), a single sentence would certainly be unwieldy.

Comment: Re: "comma hierarchy". Yes, it's something like a comma-delimited text file.  You can't have commas within the column data if you're going to use a comma-delimiter:   *...to construct, analyze, and respond to arguments;...*